# How to make global string in form2.designer.cs available in form1 in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, global-variables

I would please like to know how to make "World wide" string.

**QUESTION** :

Make string to be available in form1.cs and form2.cs

Comment: Stay away from the designer.cs file. Is not for your code to mess with. There is a clear disclaimer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simply answer is to declare the string as public static in Form1 as such:

```
public class Form1
{
  public static string TheString = "Test";
}
```

Then access it from Form2 like:

```
MessageBox.Show(Form1.TheString);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I had to play around a bit but I got my answer.